# tc: packets filter

Tags: linux, udp, filtering, tc

I need to drop UDP packets with specific UDP port number) on network interface (say eth0).
On my setup the interface eth0 is part of the bridge.

is it possible to do it using `tc` command?
if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `tc` is not for firewalling. Use [`ebtables`](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: since eth0 is part of bridge, I can do it using iptables. According to http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/iptables/user/68953 and http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=555471 I cannot use iptables rule for physical interface. Can I do something else?

Comment: Sorry, you want 'ebtables'.